# I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 over my old Ubuntu which will not boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation

I have Ubuntu 16.04 lts.

While removing some applications using synaptic my system crashed and then I restarted my laptop, but the system wouldn't boot.

Now I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 on a USB flash drive.

**How can I install Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS from the USB to my
 laptop before booting the laptop?**

Comment: look like you need a complete guide to install ubuntu http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: What do you mean by __before booting the laptop?__

Answer (score -1):

I must assume you are asking about booting from the USB instead of from the hard drive

When you start your laptop, when still on manufacturers logo screen (be quick!) you can press (depending on make/model) F2 or F12

This should bring up the efi or bios. Choose to boot from USB as first device.

You should be able to boot from the USB this way.

Comment: tryed it dosen't work

Comment: Please elaborate?

Comment: (failed) to start light display manager and

Comment: a startup job is running for hold until boot process finishes up ad then it stucking at this time

Comment: a startup job is running for hold until boot process finishes up ad then it is stucking at this time